# C# Weird encryption issue

Tags: c#

I've made my own encryption system for in my framework and I've been using it for a while now and it works fine however, I just found a serious issue: if the string that needs to be encrypted is exactly 4 characters long, the second character becomes the last character like so:

1234 > 1434

2408 > 2808

24082408 > 24082408

123  > 123

12   > 12

12345 > 12345

It really only happens when the string is exactly 4 characters, anything less/more and it works absolutely fine!

I have no idea if it's the encryption causing it or the decryption...

The code to encrypt:

```
 public static string DoEncrypt(string ToEncrypt, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(true)] bool UseHashing)
    {
        Memory.HasInitializedCheck();
        int intLenght = ToEncrypt.Length - 1;
        string NewString = null;
        for (int intCount = intLenght; intCount >= 0; intCount--)
        {

            if (intCount == 2)
            {
                NewString += ToEncrypt.Substring(intLenght, 1);
            }
            else if (intCount == 1)
            {
                NewString += ToEncrypt.Substring(intLenght - 1, 1);
            }
            else if (intCount == intLenght - 1)
            {
                NewString += ToEncrypt.Substring(1, 1);
            }
            else if (intCount == intLenght)
            {
                NewString += ToEncrypt.Substring(2, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                NewString += ToEncrypt.Substring(intCount, 1);
            }

        }
        char[] array = Application.ProductName.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(array);
        NewString += "#" + new string(array) + "#";


        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] ToEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(NewString);
        if (UseHashing)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MechaKey));
            hashmd5.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MechaKey);
        }
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(ToEncryptArray, 0, ToEncryptArray.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        String FinalEnc = Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
        return FinalEnc;

    }
```

And the code to decrypt

```
 public static string DoDecrypt(string ToDecrypt, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(true)] bool UseHashing)
    {
        Memory.HasInitializedCheck();
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(ToDecrypt);
        if (UseHashing)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MechaKey));
            hashmd5.Clear();
        }
        else
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MechaKey);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        Array.Reverse(resultArray);
        string UTF = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
        int lenght = Application.ProductName.Length + 2;
        bool start = false;
        string appname = null;
        try
        {
            if (UTF.Substring(0, lenght) != "#" + Application.ProductName + "#")
            {

                for (int appchecker = 0; appchecker < UTF.Length; appchecker++)
                {
                    if (UTF.Substring(appchecker, 1) == "#" && start == false)
                    {
                        appchecker = appchecker + 1;
                        start = true;
                    }
                    if (start)
                    {
                        appname += UTF.Substring(appchecker, 1);
                    }
                    if (UTF.Substring(appchecker + 1, 1) == "#" && start == true)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return "IDMismatch Key belongs to " + appname + " %E01";
            }
        }
        catch
        {

            return "IDMismatch Key lenght incorrect %E02";
        }


        UTF = UTF.Replace("#" + Application.ProductName + "#", "");
        char[] UTFChar = UTF.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(UTFChar);
        int intLengt = UTFChar.Length - 1;
        string NewString = null;
        for (int intCount = 0; intCount <= intLengt; intCount++)
        {

            if (intCount == 2)
            {
                NewString += UTF.Substring(intLengt, 1);
            }
            else if (intCount == 1)
            {
                NewString += UTF.Substring(intLengt - 1, 1);
            }
            else if (intCount == intLengt - 1)
            {
                NewString += UTF.Substring(1, 1);
            }
            else if (intCount == intLengt)
            {
                NewString += UTF.Substring(2, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                NewString += UTF.Substring(intCount, 1);
            }

        }
        tdes.Clear();
        return NewString;
    }


}
```

I have tried different encryption keys but it didn't change anything.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try skipping the actual encryption so you can check your intermediate values. The problem may be with the 'for' loops.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string) for an answer on encrypting and decrypting a string *without* rolling your own crypto. If you don't want to go through that effort, you'd likely be just as secure just running an XOR filter over any string's bytes.

Comment: @DougDomeny yeah it's definitely the for loop: 12345 > 32541#2noitacilppAsmroFswodniW# 321 > 321#2noitacilppAsmroFswodniW# 1234 > 3431#2noitacilppAsmroFswodniW#

Comment: Hopefully you are not using this in production code, perhaps just a class assignment?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the two cases

```
if (intCount == 1)
{
    NewString += ToEncrypt.Substring(intLenght - 1, 1);
}
```

and

```
else if (intCount == intLenght)
{
    NewString += ToEncrypt.Substring(2, 1);
}
```

With a `ToEnrypt` of lenght 4, thus `intLength = 3`, both of these conditions take the third character of `ToEncrypt`, but none of the others ever can take the second character of the string, as for inputs shorter than 5 characters you can never reach the last `else` block.

BTW shuffling the input data won't add any significant security to your encryption. Stick to well known encryption schemes and get your security from the size of the key.